# How to join two tables and iterate in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

How to write hibernate query to get list with below columns which is executed in mysql query executed in jdbc. How to write HQL query in my Main class please let me know

**Parent Entity**

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "parent_info")
public class ParentDTO {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "j", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "j")
    @Column(name = "P_ID")
    private int p_id;

    @Column(name = "P_NAME")
    private String p_name;

    @Column(name = "P_PHONE")
    private String p_phone;

    @Column(name = "P_EMAIL")
    private String p_email;

    @Column(name = "REF_ID")
    private String ref_id;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="student_id")

    private List<StudentDTO> students;


    public List<StudentDTO> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<StudentDTO> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    public int getP_id() {
        return p_id;
    }

    public void setP_id(int p_id) {
        this.p_id = p_id;
    }

    public String getP_name() {
        return p_name;
    }

    public void setP_name(String p_name) {
        this.p_name = p_name;
    }

    public String getP_phone() {
        return p_phone;
    }

    public void setP_phone(String p_phone) {
        this.p_phone = p_phone;
    }

    public String getP_email() {
        return p_email;
    }

    public void setP_email(String p_email) {
        this.p_email = p_email;
    }

    public String getRef_id() {
        return ref_id;
    }

    public void setRef_id(String ref_id) {
        this.ref_id = ref_id;
    }


}
```

**Student Entity class**

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "student_info")
public class StudentDTO {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "j", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "j")
    @Column(name = "S_ID")
    private int s_id;

    @Column(name = "S_NAME")
    private String s_name;

    @Column(name = "S_PHONE")
    private String s_phone;

    @Column(name = "S_EMAIL")
    private String s_email;

    @Column(name = "REF_ID")
    private String ref_id;

    @Column(name = "S_CLASS_NAME")
    private String s_class_name;



    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private ParentDTO parent;




    public ParentDTO getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(ParentDTO parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public int getS_id() {
        return s_id;
    }

    public void setS_id(int s_id) {
        this.s_id = s_id;
    }

    public String getS_name() {
        return s_name;
    }

    public void setS_name(String s_name) {
        this.s_name = s_name;
    }

    public String getS_phone() {
        return s_phone;
    }

    public void setS_phone(String s_phone) {
        this.s_phone = s_phone;
    }

    public String getS_email() {
        return s_email;
    }

    public void setS_email(String s_email) {
        this.s_email = s_email;
    }

    public String getRef_id() {
        return ref_id;
    }

    public void setRef_id(String ref_id) {
        this.ref_id = ref_id;
    }

    public String getS_class_name() {
        return s_class_name;
    }

    public void setS_class_name(String s_class_name) {
        this.s_class_name = s_class_name;
    }

}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<StudentDTO> groupList = null;
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();


            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**My SQL query executed in jdbc**

select pt.P_MOBILE,pt.P_EMAIL, st.S_FIRSTNAME,st.REF_ID  from parent_info pt join student_info st on pt.REF_ID = st.REF_ID  where st.S_CLASS_TO_JOIN = 10;

Comment: You have to model the relationship to your entities

Comment: can you expalin how to do this

Comment: Read about `@ManyToOne` and `@oneTo Many`

Answer (score 0):

```
String query="paste your query here ";
List<Object[]> objects = session.createSQLQuery(query).list();
                ListIterator<Object[]> iterator = objects.listIterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Object[] object = (Object[]) iterator.next();

                    int firstcolumn=(Integer) object[0];
                    int secondcolumn=(Integer) object[1];

                    }
```

Comment: i configure parent class its showing Table 'sms.parentsdto' doesn't exist